# Редирект с http на https в Putty

Tags: http, http-redirect

Начал изучать веб-технологии и уже столкнулся с таким вопросом. Использую программу **Putty**. 
Пишу:

```
GET /index.php HTTP/1.1  
Host:eldorado.ua
```

Происходит перенаправление на `Location:https:///eldorado.ua`.
Что следует делать? Как прописать при последующем запросе в `host` этот адрес.
Пишу просто `eldorado.ua`, но не помогает. Не судите строго, может не очень серьезный вопрос, но я только начал изучать данную тему и хочу разобраться во всем. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Что то я сомневаюсь, что putty умеет открывать ssl (при этом не ssh) соединения. вообще у https другой порт 443 вместо 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы совершить HTTP запрос вы вероятно используете PuTTY в режиме "raw" TCP соединения. Для HTTPS запросов необходим [TLS](https://habrahabr.ru/post/258285/).

Если вы с командной строчки хотите это выполнять, то можно использовать `openssl` клиент:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect ru.stackoverflow.com:443
```

Смотрим как пролетают данные с сертификатом, происходит TLS handshake  и вводим http запрос:

```
HEAD /questions/704792 HTTP/1.1
Host: ru.stackoverflow.com
```

После `Host` строки идёт (невидимая) пустая строчка, чтобы заголовки закончились. openssl за нас шифрует этот запрос, отправляет данные и печатает расшифрованный ответ.

Всё вместе это выполняет аналог:

```
$ curl -I https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704792
```

Можно [в Wireshark посмотреть что происходит](https://habrahabr.ru/post/253521/).

Чтобы освоиться, попробуйте [`http-prompt` утилиту](http://http-prompt.com/) или [restclient-mode в Emacs](http://emacsrocks.com/e15.html). К примеру, вот так можно сообщение в  Telegram отправить от бота:

```
:token = ...
:chat-id = ...

POST https://api.telegram.org/bot:token/sendMessage
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

chat_id=:chat-id&text=ура !
```

Получаем дешёвые push-уведомления.

Comment: Cпасибо большое