# Помогите вставить смайл

Tags: python, button, unicode

При создании кнопки для бота в телеграмм понадобилось добавить смайлик, некоторые имеющие код `\u2139` (например) работают нормально, но как вставить смайл с кодом `u+1f525` если оно последнюю 5 воспринимает как текст?

Comment: `u"\U0001F525"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> "\u2139"
'ℹ'

>>> "\U0001f525"
''
```

После `\u` всегда **4** hex-цифры идёт. После `\U` всегда **8**. См. [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Конечно, не обязательно экранирующие последовательности использовать:

```
>>> 'ℹ'
'ℹ'

>>> ''
''
```

Это создаёт те же строки:

```
>>> '' == '\U0001f525'
True
```

Это [работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/704843/23044) и для составных символов:

```
>>> '' == '\U0001f1f7\U0001f1fa'
True
```